# how to create database on mysql community server?

Tags: .net, mysql

i have just installed .NET Connector and MySql Community Server in order to create an application that is based on connecting to server through LAN

After i run the server on my computer and i type `status` I can't see the database name.
What I'm trying to do is to create a database `myDb` with 2-tables inside `users`and `tasks` and I need to add some columns on each one.

How to and What is the easiest way to create the database, table and columns, is there a something GUI for doing this ?

[image]

Comment: You can use `CREATE DATABASE myDB;`. If you want GUI, you can download Workbench.

Comment: Thank-you that helped me, i don't know whether i have to delete the question or let it help someone else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it through a GUI is to download and install [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/), create the `SCHEMA` and then the tables within it.